# How to turn off color literals in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

When editing a source file with a Swift color literal, Xcode shows a square filled with the color:

[image]

If I prefer to see the raw text representation of the literal; i.e.

```
textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

is there a way to have Xcode display the text representation instead?  I can't find an Xcode editor setting that controls this.

Comment: If you don't want to see the little colored square, don't use `#colorLiteral`. Use `UIColor`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I doubt that there is a setting.

This is more a workaround than a solution:

<kbd>⌘C</kbd> the color square – which copies the text –  and paste it as comment

[image]

Comment: Further, if you put two slashes to the left of the square, the color literal is commented out and Xcode displays the raw text.  You can edit the raw text, uncomment it, and the square reappears.