# What is the correct way to update RGB values of a colorLiteral in Xcodet?

Tags: swift, xcode

Swift provides color literals which can be written as follows:

```
#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.8431372549, blue: 0.8235294118, alpha: 1)
```

After this line of code is written, Xcode transforms it into a color image in the code as shown below.

[image]

Once it is has been automagically transformed into this image, how can I edit the specific RGB values?  (I realize I can use the color picker to pick my own color, but I would like to use specific RGB values, not try to pick a color in the UI.)

[image]

So the question is, how do you update the color to specific RGB values without deleting and re-writing the color literal?

Comment: You do realise that with the color picker UI, you can input specific RGB values, right?

Comment: A good trick for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53656466/560942

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double click on the little square, this will pop up:

[image]

press "Other". The usual macOS color picker shows up. You can then go to the second tab, and select the RGB sliders option. There is also an option to enter floating point values if you click on the gear icon:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I didn't realize I had to switch to RGB sliders on this screen.